# Visual Studio: Macro for checking configuration type (exe/dll)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

Is there a macro I can use for checking the current configuration type in visual studio?
Depending on the current setting I'd like to either include a main or dllmain function:

```
#IFDEF CONFIGURATION_TYPE_EXE

     int main(int argc, char **argv)
     {
       ...
     }
#ELSEIF CONFIGURATION_TYPE_DLL


    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

#ENDIF
```

Comment: You can define your own build configurations and preprocessor definitions in visual studio to do this for you.

Comment: Can you define 'current configuration type', do you mean Release/Debug build modes?

Comment: @simbolo no, theres an option called "configuration type" in Configuration Properties -> General, which I'd like to check for current configuration (debug/release).

Comment: @helloworld922 how can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's a DLL project, the `_USRDLL` will be defined. (see Configuration Properties\Preprocessor\Preprocessor definitions).

Be careful though, because the list is filled by wizard and will not update automatically if the project was created as something else and then configured as DLL. Also, you have to be careful if you are building a lib to be linked with a DLL.

Comment: I just tried ifdef _USRDLL on project I originally created as application. When I switch to configuration type dll it still isn't defined. So there are other project settings I'd have to change as well I guess.

Answer (score 16):

If it's dll then _WINDLL will be defined as inherited value. You can find it here: Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions.

```
#ifdef _WINDLL
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{ ... }
#else
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ ... }
#endif
```

Comment: This is more reliable than `_USRDLL` as mentioned it is inherited by a automatically included property sheet.

Comment: @MatthewHolder Though I wonder if old versions like VC6 do it automatically (I wasn't easily able to find info online about it), it seems versions even as old as VS 2008 do it. BTW, you can disable this automatic definition by clicking "Edit" on the "Preprocessor Definitions" line and uncheck "Inherit from parent or project defaults" in the box that comes up.

Comment: @KeithM, The main reason most would consider `_WINDLL` more reliable is due to it being an automatic inclusion through a build system property sheet that isn't under the user's control usually. `_USRDLL` is part of the project template which the user may remove after creating the project.

Comment: @Matthew I don't think you understood my comment the way I meant it. I'm aware of that; my concern was that I can't determine for sure how far back the history of `_WINDLL` goes. That is, VS 2008 + does it automatically, but I couldn't confirm if older versions of MSVS do. (The Question doesn't mention a specific version of MSVS.)

Comment: @KeithM, ah... I can't say for sure myself, but it's been years since I've used Visual C++ versions prior to 2005, but I can confirm that 2005 did this as well. I've used 4 and 6 and want to say they did this as well, but that would be from very very vague memories that could be easily just making me think that when it's not the case. I have always followed the convention to create a common property sheet for all configurations of a project that will put `_CONSOLE` on console apps, `_WINDOWS` on GUI apps, and `_USRDLL` on DLL apps and had my team follow that same convention.