# How to tell if current project is dll or static lib?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-linking, dynamic-linking, pragma

In a header I'd like to `#pragma comment lib` to the correct lib file depending upon whether the project including the header and being built is a dll or staticLib project.

Are there any predefined preprocessor variables I can #if on to work it out?

I've seen that `_DLL` can be used to see if the static or dynamic CRT is being used here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Why not define a macro yourself?

Comment: @HappyCoder My goal is to arrange things so that clients of my dll/staticLib can include the header and get going without any further configuration. It wouldn't be myself defining the macro it would be clients for every single project they want to use my library from.

Comment: "..project including the header..". Now I got your point.

Comment: Related (almost a dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697859/visual-studio-macro-for-checking-configuration-type-exe-dll

Comment: I doubdt it is possible. Many famouse open source libraries (libcurl, libgd, libmysqlclient, etc) require that you have to define some `config.h` file and define some symbol to set if it is lib or dll. If they can not find solution, I don't think it exists.

Comment: The Visual Studio project template wizard automagically defines `_USRDLL` when you create a project that builds a DLL.  And `_LIB` when you create a project that builds a static library.  You don't have to use them and you can certainly set your own, nothing wrong by doing this the 'standard way` however.

Answer (score 5):

There is no pre-defined macro for this functionality. [The MSDN covers these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)

However, when creating a new project of these types, Visual-studio appends the **_LIB (static library) or _USRDLL (dynamic library)** macro to the build-settings of the project.

You can reasonably assume that, given the project is created using the current visual-studio workflow, these will be defined - However, be aware this may be subject to change in future, and may not be present if the user has used a non-standard method to create the project.